# Can I host a .net web application (blog) on google app engine? Are there any tutorials on how to do it?

Tags: .net, google-app-engine

I am currently going through a tutorial for deploying an application on google app engine. The tutorial however uses python. I want to know if it can be done for C#. 
If not, is there an alternative to the app engine for .net developers?

Comment: A beta is available at this point in time: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Google App Engine "standard" environment doesn't support .NET.

The "flexible" environment (currently in beta) supports [custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/), with the proviso that it'll be running on a Docker container. So if you are able to get your web app working in a Docker container either using Mono or .NET Core, you can deploy it to App Engine Flexible Environment that way.

In terms of alternatives to App Engine - there are other cloud providers of course, and Azure is the obvious choice for running a .NET application given that it's Microsoft. It won't be the same as App Engine though - you should work out what aspects of App Engine are important to you, and make sure that wherever you end up supports those aspects.

Comment: @stylojack_10: That's not specifically about App Engine, so much as "What Google Cloud Platform means for .NET developers" - e.g. client libraries talking to GCP services, or running .NET on Google Compute Engine instances.